# Image resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event

Tags: html, http-headers, preload, web-performance

I've Googled and asked ChatGPT but haven't been able to figure this one out. I'm using link rel preload in the HTTP header so that the site's logo gets preloaded. The file being preloaded is very much on the page and visible at the top. And yet Google Chrome is complaining that the image resource was preloaded but not used.

[Here is the page](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Medicare_vs_Medicare_Advantage) where Chrome is showing the warning.

The HTTP header is:

```
Link: <https://static.example.com/css/img/diffen.svg>; rel=preload; as=image
```

The HTML in the page (which is on the www domain) where this image is used is:

```
<img height="40" width="132" src="https://static.example.com/css/img/diffen.svg" alt="Website logo">
```

At first I thought I should use `crossorigin` since the page is on the `www` subdomain and the image is on the `static` subdomain. But Googling suggested that `crossorigin` is not required for images.

Comment: Did you still try `crossorigin`? There are some types of resources that *require* it even if from the same origin (like fonts), and others that need it only if from a different origin. So your intuition seemed like a good one.

Comment: @Sheraff The warning message says the resource was successfully preloaded. If it was a CORS/crossorigin issue then the image would not have been preloaded in the first place, would it? In fact, changing the image resource and Link header to the same domain (www) still results in the same warning.

Comment: Have you fixed it? I don't see an issue. The preload seems to work as expected with no warning.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath Haven't found a fix. Chrome still shows me the warning if I load the page, wait a couple of seconds, then open dev tools. For some reason it doesn't show me that warning if I load the page with dev tools already open.

Comment: I tried different device sizes and network speeds and could not reproduce it. That page loads a lot of resources and has a lot of console errors. I'd probably focus on that before finer points, like preloading a small image that would be a high-priority load anyhow.